# Fluid images - portrait/landscape

Tags: css, image, height, fluid

I have a simple slideshow (list items) but a combination of portrait and landscape images. I'm working on a fluid grid so everything is, essentially, 100% of itself.

I'm wondering if there's a way for all the images to remain the same height, but the widths stay true to their proportions. All the images have the same height - 2000px - when uploaded.

See the site here: http://goo.gl/BdFUj

See here for the desired output: http://d.pr/i/HJUH

Thanks,
R

Comment: Yep.  With css, give them a height: 200px (or whatever) and a width of auto.  And wrap each image in a div that has the desired width to maintain the grid layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple CSS declaration;

```
img.gallery-image {  //substitute for the appropriate class, obviously
    height: 2000px;
    width: auto;
}
```

It's that easy.